# Azure Synapse Spark Pool - Add workspace package is very slow

Tags: azure, apache-spark, jar, azure-synapse, azure-synapse-analytics

I have the **Azure Synapse Analytics** Workspace and the **Spark pool** in it. I have added a .jar file (SQL Server jar file) to the *workspace packages* as shown below -

[image]

Now I am trying to add this jar file to the *Spark pool* as shown -

[image]

When I click on the Apply button, it takes more than 30 minutes to add this jar file and ultimately fails on the timeout message. I have already retried it 3-4 times and this doesn't work. Somehow the .whl file was added after multiple retries using the same method.

I have full admin access to this synapse analytics workspace.

Is this some bug from Azure or is there any other way of adding the workspace packages to the spark pool?

Thanks in advance for the help!

Sanket Kelkar

Comment: I had a similar problem once and it turned out that one of the referenced packages was not supported in the Pool. Best bet is to put in a support ticket.